# Who put a model of the Space Shuttle at the Portal of the Folded Wings Shrine to Aviation in Los Angeles Ca?

Tags: aviation-history, space-shuttle

#### Background

[This answer to *Help identifying this landmark and road in "Los Angeles 1940s, Residential Area in color"*](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/173538/59997) in Travel SE identified the structure as the:

> [Portal of the Folded Wings Shrine to Aviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_of_the_Folded_Wings_Shrine_to_Aviation):
>
> > The **Portal of the Folded Wings Shrine to Aviation** is in [Los Angeles, California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles,_California). The shrine is a 75-foot-tall (23 m) structure of marble, mosaic, and sculpted figures **and is the burial site for fifteen pioneers of [aviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation).** Designed by [Kenneth A. MacDonald Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_A._MacDonald_Jr.) and sculptor, Federico Augustino Giorgi, it was built in 1924 as the entrance to Pierce Brothers [Valhalla Memorial Park Cemetery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valhalla_Memorial_Park_Cemetery)

---

From the linked question:

> The [NASS](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1W8ShdwtfgjRHdbl1Lctcw) video [Los Angeles 1940s, Residential Area in color [60fps, Remastered] w/added sound](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yt-xhtjOReM) is a processed version of this [archived footage](https://archive.org/details/pet1182r5la).
>
> Starting at about `02:18` a movie camera points backwards from a vehicle driving down a road, pointed at the car behind but also showing few buildings and mountains in the background.
>
> However on the left there is a large, notable building...

Screenshots from the video (click for larger):

[image: screenshot from "Los Angeles 1940s, Residential Area in color (60fps, Remastered) w/added sound" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yt-xhtjOReM] [image: detail of screenshot from "Los Angeles 1940s, Residential Area in color (60fps, Remastered) w/added sound" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yt-xhtjOReM]

#### Question

Looking in Google maps there's an image that seems to be dated March 2022 https://goo.gl/maps/9igZNqgoJDqxENNS7 that shows a model of the Space Shuttle in front of the monument.

I'm curious who donated and/or build the model and since this is in a mortuary, if there is a commemoration to astronauts who lost their lives flying the Shuttle or in spaceflight in general.

There must be an interesting story here.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears the trustees of Valhalla Memorial Park had it placed in 2007 as a memorial to the crews lost in the Challenger and Columbia mishaps.

There's a good summary at [Roadside America](https://www.roadsideamerica.com/story/22900) which states:

> In 2007 the Portal was joined by a more modern, just as impressive,
> companion: a 21-foot-long model of the Space Shuttle (It's big, but
> not as big as the real thing, which is 122 feet long). Mounted atop
> some poles, nose up, landing gear down (you can spin the rubber
> tires), it's positioned as if it's about to land in the cemetery --
> because it's a memorial to the crews of the doomed Space Shuttles
> Challenger and Columbia. The insignia for Columbia is painted on its
> left side, the Challenger on its right. Plaques in the lawn directly
> below the insignia portray the seven astronauts who perished in their
> respective spacecraft. The crewmembers aren't buried with the other
> aviation stars at the Portal, but the Shuttle model serves as their
> cenotaph.
>
> In keeping with the Rotunda's theme of rebirth, the Space Shuttle
> memorial is also an example of creative recycling. It is, in fact, a
> former Hollywood movie prop, used in the ridiculous 2003 sci-fi
> disaster film The Core, where it played the Space Shuttle Endeavour.